# UIScrollview is Not Scrolling Properly After Application is Entered Background

Tags: ios, ipad, uiwebview, uiscrollview, scroll

In my application i have 3 scrollview, once the application is used for long time or application is in background for long time. Scrollview in my application is not scrolling properly and it is responding very slow compare to previously when the application is installed.

I tested the application using instruments but i am not able to find out the real cause of the application. Please help me in this issue?

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. Please show us some code of how you implement your scrollViews, we're not soothsayers, there are many ways your code could fail. In general when you ask something here, please try to describe what you've done by showing concrete examples of what works and what doesn't.

Comment: Hi, I totally used 2 direct scroll views and one web view. The other two scroll views are having my custom uiviews and in the uiwebview i directly loading the html contents taken from the web service.

Comment: The first, obvious case would be that your custom scrollViews are burdened by too much child views. I can't tell, please at least post one or two screenshots of your scrollViews, or the code that populates them...

Answer (score 0):

Hy this is gues work,
without more details one could only take a look into a glas bowl,
based on my experience scrolling has no general problems so it has to be your code which causes this problem.
I could only advise you to check your state, may adding some Log statements to show the state of your scrolling brings more light into the problem?